# Appending Something on to Variable

Tags: javascript, screen, append, resolution

I have the code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var yourImg = document.getElementById('image');
  if(yourImg && yourImg.style) {
    yourImg.style.height = screen.availWidth;
   yourImg.style.width = screen.availHeight;
  }
  </script>
```

And I need to append px to the end of the width and height.

Thanks in Advance,
Chase

Comment: -1 because this is really basic language stuff that even the most basic primers to Javascript would teach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation of strings (and other values) in javascript is made using the "+"  (plus) character. In your code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var yourImg = document.getElementById('image');
  if(yourImg && yourImg.style) {
    yourImg.style.height = screen.availWidth;
    yourImg.style.width = screen.availHeight;
    var height = yourImg.style.height + 'px';
    var width = yourImg.style.width + 'px';
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really provide much information, but:

```
screen.availWidth + 'px';
screen.availHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

yourImg.style.height = screen.availWidth+'px';

yourImg.style.width = screen.availHeight+'px';